# Can a union be initialized in the declaration?

Tags: c, initialization, declaration, unions

For example, say we have a union

```
typedef union {
unsigned long U32;
float f;
}U_U32_F;
```

When a variable of this union type is declared, is there a way to set an initial value?

```
U_U32_F u = 0xffffffff;   // Does not work...is there a correct syntax for this?
```

Comment: @Prasoon  My apologies.  I had u32 typdef'ed but not shown in the example.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use an initializer list:

```
U_U32_F u = { 0xffffffff };
```

You can set other members than the first one via

```
U_U32_F u = { .f = 42.0 };
```

Comment: Just a note that the 2nd example is a C99 feature that's not supported by all compilers.

Comment: Just another note that the 2nd is valid C++20 as well.

Answer (score 4):

Note that per-member union initialization doesn't work on pre-C99 compilers, of which there is a depressing number out there. The current Microsoft C compiler doesn't support it, for example. (I vaguely recall it doesn't even support first-member initialization, which goes back to K&R II, but I might be wrong about that.)

Comment: Microsoft more or less abandoned C and wants you to use C++ (or even better yet: C#); I'm quite content with MinGW, now that gcc-4.4 is out; in the future, Clang/LLVM might be a viable alternative as well if you're looking for a free compiler

Comment: The Microsoft C compiler does not (and to my knowledge has not, nor will) conform to any particular standard.

Answer (score 3):

Try `U_U32_F u = {0xffffffff};`