# Unable to initialize second item in a union

Tags: c, initialization, unions

I have a union with the declaration:

```
union test_u
{
    int i;
    char *str;
};
```

I am trying trying to initialize a variable with data in the "second" field, using the code:

```
union test_u test = {"Sample"};  // char *, not int
```

On attempting to compile this, I receive the error:

> file.c:72:11: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast

Is it possible to initialize the variable in the same manner I have above?  Shouldn't the compiler (under C89) accept either an `int` to `char *` in the initialization?

Comment: Where did you initialize the int?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2149001/98654

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a union be initialized in the declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148989/can-a-union-be-initialized-in-the-declaration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C89, only the first member of the union is initialised. So you can just change the order of variables in union:

```
union test_u
{
    char *str;
    int i;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

In C99, this is possible using [designated initialisers](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fstrin.htm):

```
union test_u test = { .str = "Sample" };
```

Comment: The syntax `str: "Sample"` is also possible in C89. (Not sure if it's a GCC extension though).

Comment: @Cicada: Your syntax is an old GCC extension (obsolete since GCC 2.5, but GCC supports the C99 syntax as an extension to C89): http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html